# How to download a github repository or files with curl

Tags: php, git, curl, github

I have a success to download a repository from github via `file_get_content` but what is the orientation with curl.

The advantage with the `file_get_content` it's like anonymous. In this case inside a backoffice, it's possible to download plugin in for example.

But Github restrict this usage at less 10 times, after the user must to wait long time to restart something.

It seems if the curl is used, github allow more access to download a respository.

Do you have an example to use with curl (like anonymous)?

Below an example that I make. It's works fine but it's not possible to use this several times. Think less 10 times.

Thank you

```
 public function __construct() {
  $this->githubUrl = 'https://github.com';
  $this->githubApi = 'https://api.github.com';
  $this->githubRepo = 'repos';
  $this->context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'User-Agent: ClicShopping',)));
  $this->githubRepoClicShoppingCore = 'CoreofApplication';
  $this->githubRepoName = 'addOnNameOfApplication';
}

private function getGithubRepo() {
  $url = $this->githubApi . '/' . $this->githubRepo . '/' . $this->githubRepoName;
  return $url;
}

private function getGithubCoreRepo() {
  $url = $this->githubApi . '/' . $this->githubRepo . '/' . $this->coreName . '/' . $this->githubRepoClicShoppingCore;
  return $url;
}

private function setContext() {
  return  $this->context;
}

private function getGithubApiClicShoppingCoreArchive() {
  $url = $this->githubUrl . '/'  .$this->coreName . '/' . $this->githubRepoClicShoppingCore.'/archive/master.zip';
  return $url;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Made something similar a while back, maybe its of use (dissect it) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081215/zip-download-zip-changes-folder-name-of-wordpress-theme/20082592#20082592